# Why the constructor is called if the class have a method (function) with his name?

Tags: php, function, oop, methods, constructor

Why does this code echo 'BD'? I am surprised after getting that. I am learning OOP concepts, and new to advanced php.

```
class A {
    public function a(){
        echo "A";
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public function b(){
        echo "B";
    }
}
class C extends B {
    public function a(){
        echo "C";
    }
}
class D extends C {
    public function a(){
        echo "D";
    }
}

$d = new D();
$d->a();
```

Comment: I wouldn't rely on this it will be deprecated in php7: Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP;

Comment: class classB extends A { public function b(){ echo "B"; } } After change class B to like upper code. Then why it echo 'AD'?

Comment: Ok guys i got your point. now i understood clearly. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `$d = new D();` the `B` constructor is called (because `D` inherited from `C` and `C` inherited from `B`) and when you call `$d->a();` the method `a()` of your class `D` is called and print `D` then you have as output `BD`.

From [the PHP manual on constructors and destructors](https://php-legacy-docs.zend.com/manual/php4/en/language.oop5.decon):

> For backwards compatibility, if PHP 5 cannot find a `__construct()` function for a given class, and the class did not inherit one from a parent class, **it will search for the old-style constructor function, by the name of the class**. Effectively, it means that the only case that would have compatibility issues is if the class had a method named `__construct()` which was used for different semantics.

**In your case, your class A and your class B have a constructor**

Comment: But i have not declared constructor for class B.

Comment: @MihirVadalia yes you have a constructor public function b()

Comment: @MihirVadalia do you see the reason?

Answer (score 7):

There is an ugly side effect happening. In former version of PHP the constructor of the class must have the same name as the class itself. **The name is case-insensitive**. Meaning `b` is the constructor of `B` in your case. Since `D` is a child of `B` and `D` introduces no own constructor, the constructor of `B` will get called which triggers the `B` in output.

In modern versions of PHP the constructor should be called `__construct()` to avoid such problems. However, you can still use the old mechanism, but it will trigger a notice if your error reporting level is set to `E_STRICT`.

Comment: class classB extends A {
  public function b(){
   echo "B";
  }
 }
After change class B to like upper code. Then why it echo 'AD'?

Comment: I don't get you. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @hek2mgl, He means, he's changed the constructor name from `b()` to `B()`, and now the output is `AD`

Comment: Can't reproduce this.

Comment: I changed class B function name from 'b()' to 'functionB()'. So now it not clashing with default constructor. Now it prints 'AD'.

Comment: Yeah, because `B` extends `A` and `A` defines a method `a()` .. Isn't this obvious?

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

If method is named the same as class it is used as a constructor. This is for backwards compatibility with older PHP versions.